# I want to show some text when make mouse over

Tags: css

I want to show some text when make mouse over. Can you help me please? how can I hide and show text on image?  below my code.

```css
.foodMenu {
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url(../img/burger.jpg);
 background-image: url(../img/burger.jpg);
 background-image: url(../img/burger.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 height: 210px;
 width: 280px;
 }

.foodMenu .menuTitle {
 font-size: 22px;
 text-transform: none;
 }
 
.foodMenu .menuTitle:hover {
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="col span-1-of-4 step_box">
   <div class="foodMenu"><h3 style="color:#ffffff;"    class="menuTitle">Burgers</h3></div>
</div>
```

iv>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.foodMenu {
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url(../img/burger.jpg);

    /****  Do not repeat your Commands
 background-image: url(../img/burger.jpg);
 background-image: url(../img/burger.jpg);
    ****/

 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 height: 210px;
 width: 280px;
    
    /* positioning to make the text element inside the div */
    position:relative; 
 }

.foodMenu .menuTitle {
 font-size: 22px;
 text-transform: none;

    /** position text element **/
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0; 
    left:0;
    right:0;

    opacity:0; /* opacity to hide the element */
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.75); /* background for good looking */
    transition:all 0.3s; /* animation effect */
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s; /* animation effect */
 }
 
.foodMenu:hover .menuTitle {
 opacity:1; /* opacity to show the element on mouse over */
 }
```

```html
<div class="col span-1-of-4 step_box">
   <div class="foodMenu"><h3 style="color:#ffffff;"    class="menuTitle">Burgers</h3></div>
</div>
```